# \setmathfont[range=\sqrt]{...} changes size of integrals

Tags: symbols, luatex, unicode-math, tex-gyre-math

Using the suggestion from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268088/51235), I used the `\sqrt` sign from Asana Math with TeX Gyre Pagella Math to decrease the height of some inline math. However, this apparently had some unintended side-effects. Take this minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
% comment or uncomment the next line and compare the output
\setmathfont[range=\sqrt]{Asana Math}

\begin{document}

\[
    \int ∫ \sum
\]

\end{document}
```

If you compile with or without the line `\setmathfont[range=\sqrt]{Asana Math}`, the size of the integral sign (but not the sum sign!) changes!

[image: Illustration of the issue]

What gives? The integral sign for TeX Gyre Pagella Math is very small to begin with, so this is really uncalled for! Is this a bug? Are there any more unexpected side-effects? How can I avoid this and keep both the `\sqrt` from Asana Math as well as the bigger integral sign?

For reference, I'm using the version of LuaLaTeX from the Ubuntu 15.04 repositories  (it says "This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (rev 4971)").

Comment: This is probably a bug in unicode-math. It's more difficult to combine these "tricky" symbols than ordinary letters.

Comment: I can reproduce this *only* with LuaLaTeX, not with XeLaTeX. You “fix” it by adding, as the last declaration, `\setmathfont[range=\int]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}`. It seems that math font parameters (all or some of them) are computed from the last loaded font, even if it's with a `range` option.

Comment: @egreg With that, the square root signs are too tall again, though...

Comment: I just found that someone encountered a very similar issue here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95304/51235.

Comment: The solution in the linked question indeed works, just add `\setmathfont[range={}]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}` as the last font command.